# Solving multi-dimensional linear equations with Python

Tags: python, algebra

I would like to solve a system of linear equations with Python for a physical quantity labelled U. In this case, U represents a scalar on a discrete three-dimensional grid (x,y,z) i.e. U[x, y,z]. U[x,y,z] follows the relation:

```
*a*U[x,y,z] + *b*U[x+1,y,z] + *c*U[x-1,y,z] + *d*U[x,y+1,z] + *e*U[x,y-1,z] + +f*U[x,y,z+1] + *g*U[x,y,z-1] = 0
```

The coefficients *a* to *g* are known. I know the basic procedures for solving a system of linear equations for x1,...xn in one dimension. Unfortunately, I do not understand how to proceed here at all.

Comment: You need that if the coefficients change into its value, am I right.

Comment: The coefficients are defined and fixed. One coefficient, however, might be complex.